# What does the 'GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType' option do?

Tags: .net, msbuild, csproj

What does the 'GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType' option do when set to 'true' in a csproj file?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As we can see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/dd5e8bc3f86ac98bd77d8971b00a6ad14f122f1a/src/XMakeTasks/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets#L2027) we need both `AutoGenerateBindingRedirects` and `GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType` flags to make some things for "autogenerating binding redirects" work.

`GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType` will be set to true in case you are building `exe` or `winexe` as written [here](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/blob/dd5e8bc3f86ac98bd77d8971b00a6ad14f122f1a/src/XMakeTasks/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets#L320).

So if you need binding redirects to generate while building library dlls you need to specify the `GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType` flag manually.

Answer (score 7):

It is not needed for projects that generate .exe executables but needed for unit test projects.